# xml scheme attribute or complextype conditional

Tags: xsd

I would like to allow for an element to either contain an attribute OR define a more complex type.

Something like

```
<myElement someAttr="..."/>
```

or

```
<myElement>
  <...>
</myElement>
```

That is, if someAttr exists then I do not want to allow sub elements and if it doesn't then I want to.

The reason for this is I want to have an "include" feature where I include a file which is essentially inserted into the element. But I don't want both. You can either include additional external xml code into the element or add your own BUT not both. (or also to have it inserted from a separate part of the xml)

This is mainly for simplifying a complex xml so that the structure is easily understood.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will be able to express something like that in XML schema at this point.

You *can* make an attribute optional, e.g. it can be present or not. But you cannot express something like *if the attribute is not present, then include other complex content* with the current means.

You'll have to either check this programmatically yourself, or maybe investigate if other XML description languages like [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org/) or [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) might be able to help.

Comment: I figured as much ;/ I was hoping there would be some trick to get it to work though as I'm sure it is not too uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a static choice and you change the myElement name ?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="myElementWithAttrs">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="someAttrs" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="myElementWithoutAttrs">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="skip"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I thought about that but I would like to keep the same element name for simplicity. At the moment I am simply allowing both cases to be included simultaneously.